# Opening XML file in Internet Explorer while ignoring XSL directive

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I guess I'm a bit lazy in ensuring I have an abundance of tools available on every server and VM, but when debugging an XML file, lately I am tending to open it in an environment which has just IE (in this particular case, just IE8).

So I have an XML file with an XSL directive, and IE8 opens it and applies the XSL.  However, there is underlying data in the XML which is not exposed by the XSL in its transforms, and I'd like to be able to view the XML using IE's good outline view without applying the XSL.  The data is very compact, without nice linefeeds or indentation, so basic tools available on most barebones installations like Notepad are not really viable.

Right now, I'm either outputting the file and removing the XSL line or outputting one file with the line and one without so I can use the one with XSL to give me a nicely formatted summary and the other to see everything.

Is there a setting or way to have one file with an XSL reference but just have IE not process the XSL (so I could just product one file and just turn the XSL off to see the underlying XML), or perhaps a way to have IE apply a specific XSL stylesheet on demand to an XML file which has no XSL reference (so I could produce an XSL-less file and simply point it to XSL when I want it transformed)?

Answer (score 1):

What about a lightweight XML tree viewing tool like [XML Explorer](http://xmlexplorer.codeplex.com/)?

I'm not entirely clear on what you are and aren't willing to install in your environment, but if it were me, I would prefer the above over removing/adding the  processing instruction from the XML file.

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/01/18/format-xml.aspx) shows how to format XML nicely using a few lines of PowerShell. You could optionally send the output to IE. You might find that easier than installing a viewer, as you could just paste the code into a cmd window.

Comment: I'll check it out.  With so many servers, it's easiest to have something that doesn't need an install at all, which can just run from anywhere.

Comment: @Cade: What version of Windows (Server) is on these servers?

Comment: @Cade: This page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/01/18/format-xml.aspx shows how to format XML nicely using a few lines of PowerShell. You could optionally send the output to IE. You might find that easier than installing a viewer.

Comment: It varies, Windows 2003, 2008, 2008R2.